# getting one random row from a table inside a function- sql server

Tags: sql-server, random, case, procedure, newid

i have this procedure in sql.
the requirment is:
if condition (for example i put 1=1 ..) then [run another procedure or function that will random from table with values one value and return it.] else 1
for example:

```
 case when 1=1 then (dbo.myFunc @input) else 1
```

this is myTable: '1','2','3'
and i want this function to random from it one value

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.myFunc (@input int)
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN
    declare @rndValue int
    set @rndValue = (SELECT top 1 * FROM myTable ORDER BY newID())
    RETURN @rndValue 
END
```

the problem is that in function i cannot run newID(), and if i want to use procedure instead of function i cannot run it from case statement.

what are u suggest.? thanks alot.

Comment: Also, what you have here is a ml-SVF; which are known poor performers. You would be far better off with an iTVF.

Comment: newID cannot be used in user defined funcrion that's the error i got,

Comment: iTVF what is it? it is also in sqlserver?

Comment: Is it possible to use another way instead of using a function or not ?

Comment: store procedure , or every thing u can run from case expression

Comment: I think you have a statement like this: `set x = case when ... end` or I'm wrong?

Comment: yes, i want to insert the random value to x

Comment: @מלכיג'דה-חדיד I have shown to you how to use  NEWID() in a function. Why you are posting the same question twice?

Comment: gotqn- the way u show is with add view. this is good when u have long script that craete the view and than create the function, but i just have case expression that call afunction , where eill i add the part of the view?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a code like this:

```
set x = case when 1=1 then (select top(1) val from myTable order by newid()) else 1 end;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/72657)

Comment: thank u, but this way not good for me because the part of the random is just part of my function so i cannot do like this. i   must use function ...

Comment: As want to set a random value to a variable as you accepted in question comments, I post this answer !, So, If your requirement changed, please elaborate it clearly! with adding more details, examples and your required result -HTH ;).

Comment: sorry u right! but so that i wrote that i need it in another function.